# Ionic 4 file plugin copy from the assets folder to the default directory

Tags: file, ionic-framework, copy, assets

I'm using the file plugin. and I created a folder called my_media in the default directory of my app.

```
   let path = this.file.dataDirectory; 
   this.file.createDir(path,'my_media', false);
```

Now I wanna copy an image from the assets folder to the my_media folder.

```
   let my_media = path + 'my_media'
   this.file.copyFile('../assets','default.gif', my_media , 'default.gif').then((res)=>{
     console.log("Default profile Copied Successfully")
   }).catch(err=>{
     console.log("Error to copy Image = ", err)
   })
```

But I got this error

```
  code: 5
  message: "ENCODING_ERR"
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is not possible to copy from the assets folder to the app data directory. But I can use the file from the assets folder.